# Can I use an indexed view in SQL Server to fetch only non duplicate records

Tags: sql-server, duplicates, indexed-view

We have a huge table with millions of records. We want to fetch only first record based on some key in that table. When I tried using self-join it's resulting in temp db space issue. From the performance point of view, I was thinking of using an indexed view. But I can't use left join or CTE in an indexed view.

Is there any way available to fetch only non duplicate records using indexed views?

Comment: It's been a while so i'm unsure if you can, but have you looked into using windowing functions within the indexed view?

Comment: That's a very good point - try using a windowing function instead of a self join. Indexes views are usually no solution for anything.

Comment: We have a view which is used in more than 50 places so I was thinking of achieving the desired result with minimum impact.

Comment: @RichBenner I tried rank function CTE but the indexed view is not allowing them. maybe I need to drop that views and create a table with the same name ;)  underline table updated once daily.

Comment: No, you won't be able to use a CTE but you should be able to use a window function using `ROW_NUMBER()` in your select. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/introduction-to-t-sql-window-functions/

Comment: What do you mean "first record"? Ordered by some column other than the "key" ones?

Answer (score 0):

The scenario is that an indexed view contains distinct values of the "key" that are joined to the first row on the source table.

Prepare example data

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
CREATE TABLE dbo.t (
  product_name nvarchar(20), 
  vendor_name nvarchar(20)
)
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.t (product_name, vendor_name) VALUES 
('SQL Server', 'Microsoft'),
('Oracle', 'Oracle'),
('DB2', 'IBM'),
('Oracle', 'Oracle'),
('Oracle', 'Oracle'),
('DB2', 'IBM'),
('DB2', 'IBM'),
('DB2', 'IBM');
```

Create indexed view

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.v_t', 'view') IS NOT NULL  
    DROP VIEW dbo.v_t
GO
CREATE VIEW dbo.v_t
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT COUNT_BIG(*) prod_count, vendor_name
    FROM dbo.t
    GROUP BY vendor_name
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX1_v_t
    ON dbo.v_t (vendor_name);  
GO
```

The query

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM dbo.v_t v
CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 * 
            FROM dbo.t t 
            WHERE v.vendor_name = t.vendor_name 
            ORDER BY t.product_name) t
```

Result

```
product_name         vendor_name
-------------------- --------------------
DB2                  IBM
SQL Server           Microsoft
Oracle               Oracle
```

Comment: if i change insert statement to INSERT INTO dbo.TBD_TEST (product_name, vendor_name) VALUES 
('SQL Server', 'Microsoft'),
('Oracle', 'Oracle'),
('DB2', 'IBM1'),
('Oracle', 'Oracle'),
('Oracle', 'Oracle'),
('DB2', 'IBM2'),
('DB2', 'IBM3'),
('DB2', 'IBM4'); i need only IBM1 and discard other without changing the way i use view in stored procedures

Comment: @Icarus it's a test data example to process and discard unused rows later